# Colloquially, how common is it to use the verb « partir » with the meaning of "sold out"?

Tags: expressions

During a conversation with one of my colleagues, I said:

> Les billets de leur concert sont tous **partis** presque dès qu'ils ont été mis en vente ! Ouais, comme toujours... C'est pourtant pas faute d'avoir été sur le pied de guerre avec mon portable en main !

I expressed the idea of "sold out" with the verb « partir », only to be pointed out that he is sceptical of this particular use of « partir ». Then I looked it up in multiple dictionaries, and I cannot indeed find its definition anywhere.

Is « partir » not so commonly used with this specific meaning, after all? If so, how do you idiomatically express the "sold out" idea otherwise in informal conversation, apart from using the verb « vendre », a trump card to fall back on?

Comment: The word *sold out* is often use. *Les billets de leur concert sont sold-outs presque dès qu'ils sont mis en vente*

Comment: @Laure "Ils sont partis comme des petits pains dès la mise en vente" marche aussi non ? (l'expression reste 'partis comme des petits pains' pour 'sold-out' dans ce cas)

Comment: @Weedoze Ça doit être une question de génération mais je n'ai jamais dit ni entendu ça autour de moi.

Comment: @Laure Je l'entend souvent en Belgique. Que ce soit à la télévision ou avec d'autres personnes.

Comment: @Tensibai Partir comme des petits pains est excellent à mon avis. Très familier bien sûr, mais bon à connaître pour faire « français » ! En un éclair aussi ?

Comment: @Weedoze  En Belgique, fallait dire !

Comment: @Laure Désolé de l'oubli

Comment: @Tensibai ils se sont vendus comme des petits aussi, autant que partir

Comment: @Laure oui, en un éclair, comme une fusée (ce dernier s'appliquerait plus à un mouvement qu'une vente), "Les entrées disponibles ont fondues comme neige au soleil" aussi

Comment: @Weedoze J'utilise et entend aussi l'anglicisme "sold out" (et je suis belge) mais je pense qu'on dira alors que le concert est sold out, pas les billets du concert. Exemple: https://www.rtbf.be/classic21/article/detail_indochine-vos-places-pour-le-concert-soldout?id=8214880

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas ajouter aussi une réponse pour l'emprunt _sold out_ et préciser si on a le trait d'union et l'accord en nombre en Belgique par exemple ? Merci.

Comment: Pour info encore un mélange de registre avec "être sur le pied de guerre", un peu trop recherché pour le contexte... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Les billets de leur concert sont presque tous partis dès qu'ils ont été mis en vente !

Would be more 'Frenchy' formulation, 'presque' is here to limit the 'tous' at the 'mise en vente' time. The implication is that the remaining tickets have been sold in a short time just after.

Another variation to keep your structure could be:

> Les billets de leur concert sont tous partis *quasiment* dès qu'ils *ont été* mis en vente !

for both we use the compound past 'ont été' instead of present for the moment of the opening.

From the comments alternative formulations could be:

- > Ils se sont vendus comme des petits pains dès leur mise en vente
- > Ils sont partis en un éclair dès leur mise en vente
- > Les entrées disponibles ont fondu comme neige au soleil.

Those formulations are more for oral speak than formal writing.

Comment: Hi. Regarding the placement of "presque": I put it right before "dès que" with the meaning "sold out **almost as soon as**" in mind, so that "presque" qualifies "dès que" rather than "tous". What's your take on this?

Comment: It's a good approach indeed, just not really natural to my hears, the usual formulation in french is to set the quantity to almost nothing and just imply it has gone to nothing available quickly. fo as soos as, I'd say 'quasiment dès la mise en vente' instead of 'presque' (I'll edit)

Comment: Oui, en effet. ;) Qu'est-ce qui m'a pris de faire des va-et-vient entre le passé et le présent comme ça !

Comment: "Les billets de leur concert sont tous partis *quasiment* dès qu'ils ont été mis en vente !" doesn't sound correct to me. I would prefer "Les billets de leur concert sont tous partis quasiment dès leur mis en vente !"

Comment: @C.Champagne Les deux sont correct il me semble (à la typo près: dès leur mise en vente)

Comment: Différences régionales, peut-être? Je dirais sois *quasiment aussitôt qu'ils ont été mis en vente* ou *quasiment dès leur mise en vente*, mais à mon oreille, inverser l'utilisation du *aussitôt* et du *dès* dans ces formulations sonne un peu étrange.

Comment: @Philippe aussitôt que et dès que sont synonymes, aussitôt que est rarement employé à l'oral d'après le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?34;s=685231410;r=2;nat=;sol=10;)

Comment: @Tensibai *aussitôt que* est peut-être resté un peu plus courant à l'oral au Canada. :) Pour moi, c'est simplement une questions de quels mots vont bien ensembles.

Comment: @Philippe ça devient une question de goût :) dès que ne me choque pas, je l'ai entendu un peu partout en France. Il n'y a que rarement des réponses définitives lorsqu'on parle de traduire en Français 'courant' :)

Answer (score 5):

De manière assez usuelle pour moi, j'ai [déjà lu](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/arts/dossiers/festival-dete/201407/02/01-4780472-the-killers-600-billets-envoles-en-quelques-minutes.php) aussi :

> Tous les billets se sont [envolés](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envoler) en quelques minutes.

Familièrement et de manière imagée il s'agit de l'idée de *disparaître brusquement*. L'idée de s'en *aller, s'évanouir*, voire *partir* en effet, *[en fumée](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fum%C3%A9e/35546/locution)* cadrerait plus ou moins bien, car c'est plutôt *disparaître sans profit ou résultat*, et ce serait sans doute une extension que d'interpréter un contexte où on est intéressé par l'achat de billets et où il n'y en a plus comme une telle absence de profit ou de résultat... Autrement je suis habitué de voir *partir* avec un sujet au pluriel dans un contexte de solde d'inventaire dans un locution comme *tout doit partir/disparaître* (fort similaire à *everything must go*)... tout doit être [écoulé](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9couler/27693?q=%C3%A9couler#27543).

Évidemment à l'extérieur d'un registre plus familier on a mentionné ailleurs [*vendre*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26372) pronominal, à mon avis plus clair que *partir* seul avec une précision de temps mais construit « à l'extérieur » d'une expression plus figée avec des prépositions en/comme etc. et un substantif. En d'autres mots à mon avis *se sont tous vendus* est plus clair que *sont partis + [indication de temps]*, mais pas nécessairement que *partir comme/en un éclair* etc. J'entends mieux *s'envoler* que l'auxiliaire *être* avec *partir* ici, que j'emploierais il me semble davantage avec des êtres vivants. Enfin on pourrait aussi dire, je crois, et c'est parfois techniquement exact, qu'*on a [affiché](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/complet) [complet](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/sold/613217#894353) instantanément (dès...)* puisque tous les billets se sont ainsi vendus, pour ainsi dire...

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced of the use of the verb ***partir*** here which sounds a bit awkward to me, albeit understandable. Although it may depend on regional variation in the French language, the verb ***vendre*** sounds way more appropriate in this case in my opinion.

The most common and colloquial way to say that something is sold out while emphasizing on the fact that it was sold very quickly is *se … vendre en un rien de temps*.

> Les billets se sont vendus en un rien de temps.

Of course, you could replace *se … vendre* with *partir* and get your point across, but again, this is probably not what most french people would say here.

Google results returned for:

- *"vendus en un rien de temps"* -> 214 000 results
- *"partis en un rien de temps"* -> 135 000 results
- *"vendus en un éclair"* -> 24 000 results
- *"partis en un éclair"* -> 33 000 results
- *"vendus comme des petits pains"* -> 10 000 results
- *"partis comme des petits pains"* -> 25 000 results

Comment: As a native French speaker, for sales we use more in daily speach 'partir' than 'vendre' for something we had like to buy to emphasis a sort of remorse to not have bought it in time, I feel I have to review my understanding of colloquial speech as I may totally misunderstand it

Comment: Forgot to say : for a formal language the reasoning is perfectly right

Comment: I’m also a native French speaker and I’ve never heard anyone using **partir** to express remorse in this context, here in the southwest of France. What I agree with though, is that, in a general context, **partir** is probably more often heard, mainly because it’s more vague and has a broader meaning than **vendre** since it could either be used for sth that’s free or not. That being said, when it comes to tickets or places you have to pay (since it’s what the original poster is referring to here), I most often hear the verb **vendre**, for some reasons.

Comment: I think Tensibai meant "regret" rather than "remorse", but as a native French Canadian speaker, I agree with Junitar that **partir** isn't really used to express such a sentiment.